# Problem integrating Captcha in JSF 2.0 page

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, captcha

I am following the tutorial i found in this page http://javahunter.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/integrating-captcha-in-jsf-2-0/ to integrate a captcha to my user registration form made in JSF 2.0 but i am having some problems, maybe somebody can help me. This is what i have done so far:

The JSF page:

```
<h:graphicImage id="capimg" value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/../Captcha.jpg"/>
    <h:inputText id="captchaUserInput" value="#{registrationController.captchaUserInput}"/>
<br />
    <h:commandButton value="Register"
        action="#{registrationController.doRegisterBuyer}">
    </h:commandButton>
```

The Managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class RegistrationController {
...
private String captchaUserInput;
...

public String doRegisterBuyer() throws Exception {
...<code for setting the values of the user>
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    Boolean isResponseCorrect = Boolean.FALSE;
    javax.servlet.http.HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String parm = captchaUserInput;
    String c = (String) session.getAttribute(MyCaptcha.CAPTCHA_KEY);
    if (parm.equals(c)) {

        buyersRegistratorEJB.createBuyer(buyer);

    } else {

        return "failed";
    }

    return "registrationSucceded.xhtml";
}
```

The class MyCaptcha.java(The source can be found at the link above) is a servlet that i added to a package called other inside my project

The web.xml configuration:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Captcha</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>other.MyCaptcha</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>passing height</description>
        <param-name>height</param-name>
        <param-value>30</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <description>passing height</description>
        <param-name>width</param-name>
        <param-value>120</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Captcha</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Captcha.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I think here is part of the problem, because when i navigate to my registration page i see this in the console:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Captcha]: PWC1382: Allocate exception for servlet Captcha
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: other.MyCaptcha
```

I think one of the reasons i cant implement this correctly is because the path to the MyCaptcha.java in the web.xml is not correct. How could i fix that? Also i wanted to mention, i dont want to add the change image option, only the image is fine for me.

Comment: Where is `other.MyCaptcha` located? Is it on the classpath?

Comment: It is on my project at C:\jee6workspace\BBS\src\other\MyCaptcha.java how can i add it to the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servlet is missing in the classpath. As per this comment

> It is on my project at C:\jee6workspace\BBS\src\other\MyCaptcha.java

You seem to be using an IDE. Rebuild your project, republish the project to server, restart the server. Also check the server deploy folder and make sure that the servlet is been compiled and present as `BBS/WEB-INF/classes/other/MyCaptcha.class` file.

If it is and you still have this problem, then construction/initialization of the servlet has failed (it threw an uncaught exception). Read the server logs for details and fix the root cause accordingly.

Comment: I restarted the server and builded again and fixed the problem :) tnx. I didnt know i had to do that when adding servlets to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just try the Primefaces jsf components library, which includes a captcha component. It's quite easy to use (just put  in your page).

www.primefaces.org